# Retrieve values from a SdkPublisher

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I just started working with dynamodb, and I couldnt figure out how to retrieve values from SdkPublisher.

My code is using dynamoDBAsyncClient, and I want migrate to dynamodbEnhancedAsyncClient.

I tried to use this example on https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/services-custom/dynamodb-enhanced/README.md#non-blocking-asynchronous-operations

```
List<String> tables = Flowable.fromPublisher(publisher)
                                      .flatMapIterable(ListTablesResponse::tableNames)
                                      .toList()
                                      .blockingGet();
```

But this example retrieves table names and when I adapted for my situation it blocks on "blockingGet()".